# fopen says failed to open stream: Undefined error: 0 but the fileexist is passes

Tags: php

I am trying to find the WAV file duration using the following code.

```
if ( !file_exists($location_wmv.$name_wmv) ) {
            echo "<BR> File Does not Exist<BR>";
            } else {
                echo "<BR> File Exist<BR>";
             }
        $file = $location_wmv.$name_wmv;
        $fp = fopen($file, ‘r’);
        $size_in_bytes = filesize($file);
        fseek($fp, 20);
        $rawheader = fread($fp, 16);
        $header = unpack(‘vtype/vchannels/Vsamplerate/Vbytespersec/valignment/vbits’,
        $rawheader);
        $sec = ceil($size_in_bytes/$header['bytespersec']);
        $duration_wmv = $sec;
        echo "<BR> Raw Suration.". $duration_wmv . "<BR>";
        $duration_wmv = gmdate("H:i:s", $demo_song_duration_sec);
        echo "<BR>WAV Duration".$duration_wmv;
```

Here the file_exists function says that file Exist. But the fopen says `failed to open stream: Undefined error: 0` 
The file is actually present in the folder. But still I get this error.

Comment: Well, probably the process does not have permission to open the file. Check the file permissions on file system level. Keep in mind that the http server typically runs under a separate account.

Comment: @arkascha - in that case the file_exists function would return false as well, no?

Comment: Not if you have read access for the directory, no.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
$fp = fopen($file, ‘r’);
```

looks iffy. Are those backticks?
Maybe try:

```
$fp = fopen($file, 'r');
```

(simple quotes)